# Mobile site display issues

Tags: support

When browsing a question, I noticed the text wasn't all visible on my galaxy nexus, I tried scrolling right but it wouldn't move any further. I started writing this question figuring I could paste the link, but for some reason the paste option doesn't become available only copy and cut. (Just was in my clipboard as I was going to tweet the link to Jeff and thought better of it). Instead a long press highlighted a space and i think that may have been why the copy cut options were visible. I'm using the mobile chrome web browser.

Side note, it would be nice to have a image upload (so I can show what I'm talking about from my mobile device)

EDIT

From my desktop I tracked the question down:
[Android backup/restore: how to backup an internal database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282936/android-backup-restore-how-to-backup-an-internal-database/9956801#9956801)

[image]

Comment: Connect phone to pc, use pc to upload screenshot.

Comment: Couldn't you type the question number as a starter? The above post is really useless, if you'd ask me.